# Process time increases with increase in virtual hosts threads in apache server

Tags: apache, yolov5

I’m trying to run an AI yolov5 model on 12 cameras through the flask script. I have made 12 virtual hosts with separate directory containing separate flask script for each camera.

Each virtual host is with different port number, making them port separated virtual hosts

The system specifications includes:
OS: Windows 2019 server
GPU: 12 GB RTX Geforce 2080 Ti
CPU: intel xeon, 8 cores with 3.6 GHz
RAM: 32 GB

When I’m running only one camera through virtual hosts, its performance is really good, processing upto 34 frames per second. But as I add more cameras the processing time increases. With 12 cameras each virtual hosts processes only 4 frames per second, reducing the performance.

Are the worker threads through which the virtual hosts are initialized are interfering with each other?

I have increased the thread limit of apache through winnit mpm module to 12000 threads, to spare extra threads to handle the load.

The cpu usage only goes to 35 %, RAM: 10 GB and GPU: 6 GB

Comment: Disk access limitation reached? Or the network is the bottleneck?

Comment: @arkascha How do we check the disk access limitation? and the network throughput is only half of the maximum threshold it can reach.

Comment: "only half" ... this is not about bandwidth, that is a completely theoretical value anyway that has little impact in real life applications. If you have multiple connections sharing a single network link the number of collisions mounts exponentially. Which in turn means the opposite for throughput. I have no idea if this is the case here, you'd have to investigate. Tools like `wireshark` can help with that.